# php table data into an array then post and update database

Tags: php, html

I have created a php table like so:

```
echo "<table border = '0' cellpadding ='10'>";
echo "<tr>
    <td> Question <td>Mark</td><td>Criteria</td>
    <td>Feedback</td>
    </tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
    $question[]=$rows['question']; 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row['question']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" ."<input type = 'text' name = 'mark[]' size = '1' value = '0' id = 'mark'/>/". $row['maxMark'] . "</td>";
    $maxMark[] = $row['maxMark'];
    echo "<td>".$row['criteria']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input name = 'feedback".$counter."' id= 'feedback' value='Enter feedback'>". "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $counter++;
}

echo "</table>";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "</table>";
```

I want to get the all the data i input from mark and put it into an array and then post it to another page and update my database.
The only thing i am having trouble with is getting the values i input and putting them all in an array

any help would be appreciated
:)

Comment: `cellpadding ='10px'` is wrong, use `cellpadding ='10'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the form array notation ...

```
echo '<input type="text" name="data[mark]', $counter ,']" />';
echo '<input type="text" name="data[feedback][', $counter ,']" />';
```

then everything will be array

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

p.s. you should use double-quotes for html tag attributes and echo with ',' rather than '.'